# How do I find out if the space character is in a NSString more than once?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

How do I find out if the space character is in a NSString more than once?  It seems like a simple thing but while looking through the NSString methods I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: I found your question about stock market bots and I'm working in something similar. Could you send me an email to lisandro_v22@hotmail.com or add me to G+ http://goo.gl/vLeie ? I really want to chat

Answer (score 2):

```
([string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].count - 1) > 1
```

Comment: @H2CO3 In this specific case the `x - 1 > 1` form is better, since it preserves the semantic meaning of `more than once`.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Not a major point, but here I disagree. At the same time it does so against readability...

Comment: If you read that code, you'd probably wonder why `> 2` and not `> 1`. Where does the `2` come from? Therefore you would need to go thru the process that brought you to add an extra 1 on the right side.